# Exploring the processes/threads of a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: process, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Is there a Process Explorer-like application for Windows Phone 8 devices? We're trying to debug what we think are bugs related to processes but having a hard time trying to get at them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot access processes that are outside of your application sandbox on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

This is only doable with internal tools, and not available to 3rd party developers. Instead, please report your concerns (with a sample to repro) on MSConnect or the MSDN forums.